# python: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have created a Django project "post_blog" in which I have created an app "blogs".

```
C:Users/arpchauh/PycharmProjects/post_blog/blogs>python manage.py runserver
python: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: Can we please see your directory structure?

Comment: Show your complete project directory tree and error trace back.

Comment: It seems that you are not in a directory where manage.py is located. I think `manage.py' in post_blog directory itself and you should issue the command from there. It would be helpful If u post your directory structure

Answer (score 20):

`manage.py` should live in the root project folder, so if you `cd` into `C:Users/arpchauh/PycharmProjects/post_blog`, you should be able to run the command.

Answer (score 5):

Your `manage.py` file should be located in the root directory of the project. You need to be in the directory that `manage.py` is in.

Answer (score 2):

One error that might be leading to this is entering

```
django-admin startapp app_name
```

instead of

```
django-admin startproject project_name
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you start the django application

```
django-admin startporject my_project_name
```

you need to navigate inside the my_project_name folder and then launch

```
python manage.py runserver
```

If you are still getting some error, do check where is your python interpreter taking the django setup from

Answer (score 0):

The `manage.py` file must be available at the root of the project folder. If it is in any sub-directory, it'll give you error.
If you are limited to keeping the file in the sub-directory, you can change the permission of folder, so the python cli can read it.

Answer (score 0):

*Your manage.py file should be located in the root directory of the project. You need to be in the directory that manage.py is in and then run the server
**python manage.py runserver***

Answer (score 0):

your "manage.py" file is in the "post_blog" folder and you are giving a command in the following directory
C:Users/arpchauh/PycharmProjects/post_blog/blogs>

if you focus there is no manage.py file in the blogs folder that why its creating an issue

Use this one, I hope it will resolve your issue

**C:Users/arpchauh/PycharmProjects/post_blog> python manage.py runserver**

Answer (score -1):

It's very simple. You are not inside the project root folder (you are in your blog app folder). make sure you change the directory to the project folder and run those commands.
use `cd` command to change directory

```
cd C:Users/arpchauh/PycharmProjects/post_blog
// or move one step backword
cd ..
```

Answer (score -2):

Refer to my project path C:\Users\sharpfungs\Desktop\django\djangosite to match with yours.
Make sure your virtualenv is active as (myproject) C:> for windows.
Then run run the server in the root of project folder.